# Blurry textures after resize on certain computer?

Tags: c#, xna

So here's the thing. I made a game in 192x108. Yes, that small. I also made it borderless windowed, and it also resizes and stretches itself to it fits the main screen.

HERE'S THE PROBLEM:
When I start the game on my home PC, it stretches out to 1920x1080 with nearest neighbor and it's not blurry at all, just a pixely beauty. BUT when I start the game on my school PC, it stretches out to 1366x768 and becomes BICUBIC? I even added PointClamp to the spriteBatch.Begin(...SamplerState.PointClamp), but there was NO difference.

So how come it's different depending on the PC I use?

Comment: Have you tried to set your pc resolution as schools is?

Comment: Wow, the game still looked good after I did that. No difference. Home PC still looks good.

Comment: I would imagine it comes down to graphics card settings, I don't know if times have changed (or my school was cheap) but I'm pretty sure the computers I was using in school had integrated graphics cards

Comment: Or maybe some kind of software issue...DirectX version? :/

Comment: Well, I have updated everything I can through Windows Update, so I don't know...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can do this for every frame outside of the sprite batch:

```
GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.PointClamp;
```

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6820/how-do-i-disable-texture-filtering-for-sprite-scaling-in-xna-4-0

However, I'm wondering if it isn't the sprites that are being scaled, but the device after the sprites are rendered. Hard to tell without more information. Make sure your DisplayMode, ClientBounds, ViewPort, and BackBuffer are all the same width and height as well.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203889(v=xnagamestudio.31).aspx

Comment: None of this helped, sorry. Remember that it only happens on one computer, my school Laptop. Changing to other SamplerStates shows a clear difference on my PC, but it's always Bilinear on my Laptop...

Comment: Okay, it may be impossible to answer this without actually having access to your laptop. Someone might have some inspiration that might help, but this is a bit like trying to diagnose car problems with a car you can't touch or even see. You can make guesses based on previous experience but if those guesses are wrong, all people can do is either keep guessing or give up.

Comment: Yeah it's probably game over... But if it helps: It seems my PC can only have Nearest Neighbor, while as previously stated my Laptop only has Bilinear. Regardless of the SamplerState. - That or I don't know how to code ._.